# Selected row (object) in dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have class

```
public class Students
{
    public int StudentsID { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
}
```

And I use a list of objects. Then I add the objects from the file and display this list in datagridview like that:

```
List<Students> listStudents = new List<Students>();
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < listStudents.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(listStudents[i].name, listStudents[i].StudentsID);
}
```

And now is the question. How would I know which object is selected.
I tried this, but it does not work - currentObject is null

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Students currentObject = (Students)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
}
```

Comment: Your data grid view is not databound.

Comment: You should be binding your grid to that list... Look at the [DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem?view=net-5.0) and specifically the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem?view=net-5.0#examples).

Comment: Instead of populating the grid manually just set the `DataSource` property with that list. Or, even better, if you use a [`BindingSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource) between them, then its `Current` property will always contain the currently selected item regardless of the type of the bound control (which can be a grid, list box, combo box or anything that has a `DataSource` property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People who are new to using Winforms and DataGridViews, tend to add the rows of the DataGridView themselves.

But there is a much easier way: use the `DataSource` of the DataGridView.

You plan to show `Students` in your DataGridView. You'll probably have two columns, the one where you show the StudentsId, and the one where you show the Name.

Every DataGridViewColumn has a string property [DataGridViewColumn.dataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=net-5.0) This property contains the name of the property that this column should show.

So to show the Id and the name, you need something like:

```
columnStudentId.DataPropertyName = nameof(Student.StudentId);
columnStudentName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Student.Name);
```

You will probably set these properties using the visual studio designer.

Now to show the Students, one Student per row, all you have to do is assign the collection to the DataSource of the DataGridView:

```
List<Student> students = ...
this.DataGridView1.DataSource = students;
```

And bingo, the names and id of every Student is shown in the DataGridView.

The solution is a one-time only: changes are not recorded. If you want that changes in the table are updated automatically, put the items in a `BindingList<Student>`:

```
private BindlingList<Student> students;

private void DisplayStudents(IEnumerable<Student> students)
{
    this.students = new BindingList<Student>(students.ToList());
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.students;
}
```

Any changes made by the operator are automatically updated in `this.students`, any change that you make to `this.Students` is automatically displayed.

```
private void AddOrUpdateStudent(Student studentToUpdate)
{
    // Is there already a Student with this Id shown?
    var existingStudent = this.Students
        .Where(student => student.StudentId == studentToUpdate.StudentId)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (existingStudent != null)
    {
         // Student exists, update the name:
         existingStudent.Name == studentToUpdate.Name;
    }
    else
    {
         // Student does not exist yet; add it:
         this.Students.Add(studentToUpdate);
    }
}
```

The datagrid view is automatically updated.

Similarly the other way round: operator edits one or more cells in the datagridview and presses a button:

```
private void OnButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    // all edited cells are already updated in this.Students:
    this.ProcessStudents(this.Students);
}
```

To get the Student that is displayed in a certain row, you can use property [DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem?view=net-5.0)

```
IEnumerable<Student> selectedStudents = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => (Student)row.DataBoundItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listStudents.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(listStudents[i].name, listStudents[i].StudentsID);
}
```

add your list to Datagridview datasource :

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = listStudents;
```

to get the current row as object :

```
Students currentObject = (Students)dataGridView2.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

Answer (score -2):

Just do this:

```
List<Students> listStudents = new List<Students>();
...
dataGridView2.DataSource = listStudents;
```

And get rid of the "for" loop.